# Generalized McShane Identity for Closed Riemann Surfaces

Tags: moduli-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmuller-theory

There is an identity for the hyperbolic Riemann surfaces with at least one border. The identity is known as Generalized McShane Identity or Mirzakhani-McShane Identity proved by Mirzakhani in her [seminal paper](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~mlyubich/Archive/Geometry/Teichmuller%20Space/Mirz3.pdf) (Theorem 4.2).  The questions are

- Is there a similar kind of identity for the hyperbolic Riemann surfaces without any border and/or punctures?
- For example, what is the WP volume of the moduli space of hyperbolic Riemann surfaces of genus two? How can we compute it?

Comment: For genus 2 surfaces, see: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2210106 , http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2215456

Comment: @IanAgol, Thank you for the reference. I am also looking for a version that Mirzakhani's integration argument can be applied. 

There is an identity obtained by Luo and Tan: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.2133.pdf

Or for small surfaces:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.1573.pdf
However, it is not quite clear to me how to apply Mirzakhani's logic in this case. 

The volume can be obtained through Do-Norbury result:
http://www.ms.unimelb.edu.au/~norbury@unimelb/papers/dilaton.pdf

But, I am trying to understand the integration procedure itself, not the final result.